# How to open pdf files stored in assets folder while i am using listview?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some list of 6 subjects,I want to load different pdf file when i click on different list items.Every list item should migrate to their respective subject  pdf file  ??How can this be possible by using only one activity and getting migrated to multiple pdf files by their respective item on click ?? Can anyone help me with this ??
[activity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIt1v.png)

[activity1.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceawL.png)

Comment: did you try anything? because how would we know that what kind of migrate subject you tell about..??

Comment: Yes i tried but i have multiple activities !!That means for every subject i have created a activity to load its pdf file that increasing no. Of activities in my project to reduce it to one activity how to proceed??

Comment: why are you created different activities ?? you have to just give pdf source to same activity when you clicked on list item.

Comment: I have attached some images please check that and say me what changes i have to do

Comment: valuses String Array is ListItems right??

Comment: Yes its list items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code at where you wanted to handle listview click

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(this,PdfActivity.class); // Common activity for all
                i.putExtra("position",position); // send position to Intent
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

and on other activity which is `PDfActivity` which I called , you can change name whatever you want ... do below in `onCreate()`

```
    int position = 0;
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
   position = bundle.getInt("position") // String Which are send through intent
        }



 if(position==0){
      //  view.fromAsset(<your file Name in position 0 on the list>.pdf).load();
   } else if(position==1){
   // view.fromAsset(<your file Name in position 1 on the list>.pdf).load();
   }else if(position==2){
    //view.fromAsset(<your file Name in position 2 on the list>.pdf).load();
   }else if(position==3){
    //view.fromAsset(<your file Name in position 3 on the list>.pdf).load();
   }else if(position==4){
    //view.fromAsset(<your file Name in position 4 on the list>.pdf).load();
   }

   and So on.....
```

Comment: welcome.. for more http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html read this for basic concept..

Answer (score 1):

```
   //in your on create motod do it 
   listView=findViewById(R.id.grid_View);
  UnlockAdapter adapter= new UnlockAdapter(Home.this,values);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "you pressed on"+position, 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String str_pos = String.valueOf(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Sub_Details.class);
        intent.putExtra("myKey", str_pos);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
 // here is the activty where you send your intent(Sub_Detail)

 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  String tmp = extras.getString("myKey");
  Toast.makeText(this, "new Activity: "+tmp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  int tmps= Integer.parseInt(tmp);
  // now do whatever you want on that position


  if (tmps==0){
   
    pdfview.fromAsset("1.pdf").load();
  }
  if (tmps==1){
   pdfview.fromAsset("2.pdf").load();
  }
  if (tmps==2){
   pdfview.fromAsset("3.pdf").load();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

> Using this library open pdf file [Android PdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Comment: Am not able to understand that code which you have sent ,By intent.putextras(......),we can attach the values and key to move right ???do you know how to do it

Comment: I not understand your concept please  explain

Comment: i  have attached some images regarding it

Comment: pass the position or path of file use in the class

Comment: It is in assets folder so by using intent how to pass the path of the assets folder and load it

Comment: In place of link what we have to specify our "pdf name" ??